# FCM notification not received when the app is swiped or force closed

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a FCM display notification that's handled automatically by system trey & send data as an intent, but when I try to swipe or force stop my app the notification doesn't shown anymore.

Is there any workaround to make the app restart after force stop?

The phone's brand tested with is Samsung & Huawei

**Note:**

I don't have a custom service for Firebase notification because display notification is enough for my situation.

**What I have tried so far:**

1- I tried to make a custom firebase notification service and implement the onMessageReceived but the same problem happens.

2- I tried to make a Notification Service that return START_STICKY and is started by a broadcast receiver and the broadcast receiver called when the Notification Service onDestroy executed as the telegram does, but the same problem happens.

Comment: You need to implement the Firebase services in your app, even if you do nothing with the data received

Comment: see this link that may help you : https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/378

Comment: It doesn't work @Pierre

Comment: It doesn't work too @HyperMax